# Use column alias in dataProvider

Tags: yii, dataprovider

In my model I have a `relation()` like this.

```
        'notRelUser' => array(
            self::HAS_MANY,
            'LocationUser',
            'location_id',
            'condition' => 'notRelUser.status is null',
            'on' => 'notRelUser.user_id = ' . Yii::app()->user->getId(),
            'with' => array('parent_location'),
            'select' => array('*', 'name AS canApply'),
        ),
```

and this

```
public $canApply;
```

In my controller I have this

```
    $regions = Location::model()->with('notRelUser')->findAll();
    $arrayCanApply = new CArrayDataProvider($regions);
```

I then am trying to print out the value of **canApply** in a widget for datagrid

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$arrayCanApply,
'columns'=>array(
    array('name'=>'name', 'header'=>'Name'),
    array('name' => 'canApply', 'value'=>'$data->canApply', 'header'=>'CanApply'),
 ),
 ));
```

But the column with canApply is empty.

I have also tried without the `$data->` part.

How can I print this alias?

(I know the value of the alias i trivial, but I will change that later)

**UPDATE:**

I can get the value by using select in `CDbCriteria` - but I want to do it in relation.

This does work.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = '("foobar") AS canApply';
$regions = Location::model()->with('notRelUser')->findAll($criteria);
```

but it seems odd that I have to create a $criteria on everytime

Answer (score 2):

you need to declare can canApply as an attribute of the model

in your model decalare canApply as an attribute

```
public $canApply;
```

Comment: I already did that, but maybe I didn't wrote it good enough in the question. The value is still null.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. Try `'value'=>'$data->notRelUser->canApply'`
instead of `'value'=>'$data->canApply'`. Also, you need to declare attribute

```
public $canApply;
```

in your `LocationUser` model, not in `Location` model.